# How far does the Offline-first feature of gunJS go ?

Tags: javascript, persistence, offline-caching, gun, gundb

I would like to know how the data is persisted(saved) on the device, does it survive a reboot ? or a restart of the browser ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the author of gun:

> it depends on the device. In case of the browser, localStorage is used
>   and can survive reboot, reload, etc.
>
> If it is in NodeJS, most storage adapters (the current default
>   file.js, the upcoming default RAD, and others) store to disk (and even
>   some, to S3, IPFS, etc.) which survive reboot and can even migrate
>   between machines (like with Heroku) for the latter adapters.

source: https://github.com/amark/gun/issues/529